# Chrome devtool console drawer showing automatically

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm having a problem with the console drawer on Chrome dev tool. Every time there's an error on the page, it popups automatically. I would like to disable this feature.

I know about the esc key to close it, but it's still very annoying.

I've found a few questions about this, but all the answers were out-dated (ex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819685, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420516)

I'm using Chrome Version 49.0.2623.87 with no extension.

Here's an image to better explain the problem:

[image: Drawner pops up automatically]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer was found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159780/drawer-panel-keeps-showing-up-on-refresh

I had to:

1. Uncheck "Enable JavaScript source maps"
2. Uncheck "Enable CSS source maps"

in the devtools settings (F1 key while devtools is opened, or click the three dots button in the devtools window). It seems to be a bug in Chrome related to source maps.

Answer (score 3):

I had accidentally enabled **Open Devtools window and ...**  . Unchecking that fixed this issue for me.

[image: option to disable]